# remove last word in label split by \

Tags: c#, split

Ok i have a string where i want to remove the last word split by \

for example:

```
string name ="kak\kdk\dd\ddew\cxz\"
```

now i want to remove the last word so that i get a new value for name as

```
name= "kak\kdk\dd\ddew\"
```

is there an easy way to do this

thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

How do you get this string in the first place? I assume you know that '' is the escape character in C#. However, you should get far by using

```
name = name.TrimEnd('\\').Remove(name.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
string result = string.Join("\\",
            "kak\\kdk\\dd\\ddew\\cxz\\"
            .Split(new[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Reverse()
            .Skip(1)
            .Reverse()
            .ToArray()) + "\\";
```

Comment: Admittedly, a bit. But it's obviously correct, isn't it? No messing with indexes in the string, or cryptic regex's etc.

Comment: I find it frightening that you where able to come up with that solution...  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a non-regex manner of doing it.

```
string newstring = name.SubString(0, name.SubString(0, name.length - 1).LastIndexOf('\\'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex replacement should do the trick:

```
name = Regex.Replace(name, @"\\[a-z]*\\$", "\\");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const string separator = "\\";
string name = @"kak\kdk\dd\ddew\cxz\";
string[] names = name.Split(separator.ToCharArray(), 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = String.Join(separator, names, 0, names.Length - 1) + separator;
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:I just noticed that `name.Substring(0,x)` is equivalent to `name.Remove(x)`, so I've changed my answer to reflect that.

In a single line:

```
name = name = name.Remove(name.Remove(name.Length - 1).LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

If you want to understand it, here's how it might be written out (overly) verbosely:

```
string nameWithoutLastSlash = name.Remove(name.Length - 1);
int positionOfNewLastSlash = nameWithoutLastSlash.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
string desiredSubstringOfName = name.Remove(positionOfNewLastSlash);
name = desiredSubstringOfName;
```

Answer (score 1):

My Solution

```
 public static string RemoveLastWords(this string input, int numberOfLastWordsToBeRemoved, char delimitter)
        {
            string[] words = input.Split(new[] { delimitter });
            words = words.Reverse().ToArray();
            words = words.Skip(numberOfLastWordsToBeRemoved).ToArray();
            words = words.Reverse().ToArray();
            string output = String.Join(delimitter.ToString(), words);
            return output;
        }
```

Function call

```
RemoveLastWords("kak\kdk\dd\ddew\cxz\", 1, '\')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string name ="kak\kdk\dd\ddew\cxz\"
string newstr = name.TrimEnd(@"\")
```

Comment: Even if you add semicolons, that doesn't compile (or work). TrimEnd takes "params char[]", not string. And if you fixed the argument, the result would be "kak\kdk\dd\ddew\cxz", which is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

if you working with paths:

```
  string name = @"kak\kdk\dd\ddew\cxz\"; 
  Path.GetDirectoryName(name.TrimEnd('\\'));
  //ouput: kak\kdk\dd\ddew
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] temp = name.Split('\\');
string last = "\\" + temp.Last();
string target = name.Replace(last, "");
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations when you answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

For Linq-lovers: With later C# versions you can use SkipLast together with Split and string.Join:

```
var input = @"kak\kdk\dd\ddew\cxz\";
string result = string.Join( @"\", input
                        .Split( @"\", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
                        .SkipLast( 1 ))
                + @"\";
```