# How to cut a string to the first "/" from right to left c# .net

Tags: c#, .net

I need to remove from my string the last section from the `"\"`

```
          Input: C:\qaweb2094\Site\dasdasd.pdf
Expected Output: C:\qaweb2094\Site
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove last word in label split by ∖](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155668/remove-last-word-in-label-split-by)

Comment: If it's always a filename, use [Path.GetDirectoryName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname) (here's a [demo](https://rextester.com/WBK19220)]). If not, check the answers in the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
string s = "C:\\qaweb2094\\Site\\dasdasd.pdf";
if (s.Contains("\\"))
{
    s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf("\\"));
}
```

Comment: @SowmyadharGourishetty  Thank you very much, it is working, and thanks for the corrections RufusL

Comment: But, if you are always parsing a path, and the result you want is the file name, then using `Path.GetDirectoryName` as suggested by @AhmedAbdelhameed is a better solution - if for no other reason than it makes your intention clear to a reader of your code.